# NDK not configured (although it is installed)—how to fix without Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an Android project with Gradle. The project uses native code and thus needs NDK, which I have installed.

However, Gradle fails with the following error:

```
> NDK not configured. 
  Download it with SDK manager.
```

Android’s SDK Manager does not list NDK as an option. Besides, I have NDK installed on my box, so the error seems to be that Gradle isn’t finding it.

Most answers assume users to have Android Studio, which I do not have and do not want. Any way to fix this without?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have an environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` set and pointing to your NDK install directory. In my case this did the trick:

```
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/home/myself/bin/android-ndk-r10e
```

You may want to add this to your `.bashrc` or similar to have the variable inserted at login, or run the command above each time you launch a shell and want to build an NDK project.

As an alternative, if you installed `ndk-bundle` through `sdkmanager`, it will be found without an extra environment variable.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using the Linux command line to install a specific build `yes | ./sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.0.6113669"` and was using NDK_ROOT and NDK_HOME to point to install but the env variable I needed was `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`.  That variable seemed to be set if you do `--install ndk-build` but that always installs the latest version.  I got those versions from `./sdkmanager --list`

Answer (score 15):

> Most answers assume users to have Android Studio, which I do not have
>   and do not want. Any way to fix this without?

Yes, you don't have to install Android Studio.

For your existing Android project, I expect that you already have `local.properties` under your root dir of your project. Open and modify there to set your NDK dir. For example, your NDK version is **android-ndk-r17b** (https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/), and you have installed (or  unzipped) it in directory `/Users/myname/foo/xxx/Android/android-ndk-r17b`, then modify this file as below:

```
ndk.dir=/Users/myname/foo/xxx/Android/android-ndk-r17b 
sdk.dir=/Users/myname/foo/xxx/Android/sdk
```

Comment: This answer is useful also if you have Android Studio, and got code from another developer which included their `local.properties`. You can edit their `local.properties` and delete the line with `ndk.dir` that points to their local machine folder, if your Android Studio is already configured with the correct folder on your machine. Then gradle sync and the error would be gone.

Comment: FYI this is now slightly outdated due to deprecation of the ndk.dir configuration in local.properties. It still works (for now) but the recommended approach is now outlined here for setting this correctly: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio#4-0-0-ndk-dir